# Filtering by length of lines in file giving unexpected result

Tags: haskell, io, pipe

I am working my way through Learn You a Haskell for great good. I am currently on the files and streams section of Chapter 9. For some reason, when I try to pipe code into one of the example Haskell programs, I do not get the same output as the book. Using ConEmu for Linux commands on Windows. For example, I have the program that only prints out strings that are less than 10 characters with the code below (short_lines.hs):

```
main = interact $ unlines . filter ((<10) . length) . lines
```

I am going to be passing this file (short_long.txt):

```
i'm short
so am i
i am a loooooooooong line!!!
yeah i'm long so what hahahaha!!!!!!
short line
loooooooooooooooooooooooooooong
short
```

Here is the command:

```
cat short_long.txt | runhaskell short_lines.hs
```

Here is my output:

```
so am i
short
```

The book says that the output is the following:

```
i'm short  
so am i  
short
```

I believe this has to do with the handling of the newline character but I can't figure this out since lines should have removed the newline characters before filtering. It works with manual input but not with piping. Why am I getting a different output? Am I doing something wrong? I tried removing trailing newline characters in Atom editor but it didn't change anything. Any help on why I am not getting the expected result and what I could do to get the expected result would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Weird. Check for trailing spaces. Check the `'` to be a standard quote. Try `main = interact $ unlines . map (show . length) . lines` to print the lengths of all the lines.

Comment: What is the output of the program `main = getContents >>= print` when given the problematic input?

Comment: This was really helpful. I found that the output was `"i'm short\r\nso am i\r\ni am a loooooooooong line!!!\r\nyeah i'm long so what hahahaha!!!!!!\r\nshort line\r\nloooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\r\nshort\r\n"`. I then did some searching and found out about the Windows carriage return vs Unix. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default newline mode for stdin is [`nativeNewline`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Handle.Types.html#nativeNewline), which chooses its behavior based on what it believes your OS to be. I suspect that it has  (wrongly) decided you are on a Unix system and it therefore should not do CRLF conversion; thus when given a Windows-style file each line has a trailing `'\r'` character. Try using

```
import System.IO

main = do
  hSetNewlineMode stdin universalNewlineMode
  interact $ unlines . filter ((<10) . length) . lines
```

to force CRLF conversion and see if that gets you the expected results.

I can reproduce your problem on my Unix system by converting a text file to DOS mode before giving it to your program. Having done so, my suggested fix  gets the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I can change the line ending style from Windows-CRLF to Unix-LF on Atom editor. Currently it is located on the bottom and simply says CRLF or LF. You can click on it to choose a different line style. For this book, that is what I will use for simplicity's sake. However, I believe that amalloy's answer is a better long-term universal approach to IO.